# JavaScript - Promise.allSettled + Array.reduce()

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

### Introduction

Imagine this method for getting the language of a user:

```js
const getUserLanguage = (userId) => new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
        if (Math.random() < 0.3) resolve("en");
        if (Math.random() < 0.6) resolve("es");
        reject("Unexpected error.");
    }
);


(async () => {
    try {
        const language = await getUserLanguage("Mike")
        console.log(`Language: ${language}`);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

Now, I am trying to group the language of multiple users, performing a parallel request:

```js
const getUserLanguage = () => new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
        if (Math.random() < 0.3) resolve("en");
        if (Math.random() < 0.6) resolve("es");
        reject("Unexpected error.");
    }
);

const groupUsersByLanguage = async (userIds) => {
    const promiseResults = await Promise.allSettled(
        userIds.reduce(async (acc, userId) => {
            const language = await getUserLanguage(userId);

            (acc[language] = acc[language] ?? []).push(userId);

            return acc;
        }, {})
    );
  
    console.log({ promiseResults });
  
    // Filter fulfilled promises
    const result = promiseResults
        .filter(({ status }) => status === "fulfilled")
        .map(({ value }) => value);
  
    return result;
}

(async () => {
    const userIds = ["Mike", "Walter", "Saul", "Pinkman"];
    const usersGroupedByLanguage = await groupUsersByLanguage(userIds);
    console.log(usersGroupedByLanguage);
})();
```

### Problem

But my implementation is not working:

```
const promiseResults = await Promise.allSettled(
    userIds.reduce(async (acc, userId) => {
        const language = await getUserLanguage(userId);

        (acc[language] = acc[language] ?? []).push(userId);

        return acc;
    }, {})
);
```

How can I do for getting an output like

```
{
    "es": ["Mike", "Saul"],
    "en": ["Walter"],
}
```

using the `Promise.allSettled` combined with `.reduce`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.reduce` is constructing an object where each value is a Promise. Such an object is not something that `.allSettled` can understand - you must pass it an array.

I'd create an object outside, which gets mutated inside a `.map` callback. This way, you'll have an array of Promises that `.allSettled` can work with, and also have the object in the desired shape.

```js
const getLanguage = () => new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
        if (Math.random() < 0.3) resolve("en");
        if (Math.random() < 0.6) resolve("es");
        reject("Unexpected error.");
    }
);

const groupUsersByLanguage = async (userIds) => {
    const grouped = {};
    await Promise.allSettled(
        userIds.map(async (userId) => {
            const language = await getLanguage(userId);
            (grouped[language] = grouped[language] ?? []).push(userId);
        })
    );
    return grouped;
}

(async () => {
    const userIds = ["Mike", "Walter", "Saul", "Pinkman"];
    const usersGroupedByLanguage = await groupUsersByLanguage(userIds);
    console.log(usersGroupedByLanguage);
})();
```

An option that doesn't rely on side-effects inside a `.map` would be to instead return both the userId and the language inside the map callback, then filter the `allSettled` results to include only the good ones, *then* turn it into an object.

```js
const getLanguage = () => new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
        if (Math.random() < 0.3) resolve("en");
        if (Math.random() < 0.6) resolve("es");
        reject("Unexpected error.");
    }
);

const groupUsersByLanguage = async (userIds) => {
    const settledResults = await Promise.allSettled(
        userIds.map(async (userId) => {
            const language = await getLanguage(userId);
            return [userId, language];
        })
    );
    const grouped = {};
    settledResults
        .filter(result => result.status === 'fulfilled')
        .map(result => result.value)
        .forEach(([userId, language]) => {
            (grouped[language] = grouped[language] ?? []).push(userId);
        });
    return grouped;
}

(async () => {
    const userIds = ["Mike", "Walter", "Saul", "Pinkman"];
    const usersGroupedByLanguage = await groupUsersByLanguage(userIds);
    console.log(usersGroupedByLanguage);
})();
```

Comment: That feels like an abuse of `map`.  A `reduce` would make more sense to me.

Comment: Yeah, the side-effects inside feel weird, but given that the input is an array, and that one part of the output must be an another array of Promises one-to-one with it, I'm not sure if there's something else that'd look better. I'm not so happy with [`.reduce` when turning into a single object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg)

Comment: I don't share that objection, although I've seen that video before (and also the Rich Snapp antipattern post), but I would choose `forEach` over `map` here.  `map` should be used in only one way, to my mind.

Comment: `.map(result => result.value).forEach(([userId, language]) => ...)` could also be written as `.forEach(({ value: [userId, language] }) => ...)` but I would personally use the first solution in this answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a main function using two utility functions for this: one that groups a set of elements according to the result of a function, and one that takes a predicate function and partitions an array into those ones for which it returns `true` and those ones for which it returns `false`.  These two in turn use a `push` utility function which simply reifies `Array.prototype.push` into a plain function.

The main function maps the `getUserLanguage` function over the users, calls `Promise.allSettled` on the results, then we map over the resulting promises, to connect the original `userId` back with the promise results.  (If the fake `getUserLanguage` returned an object with properties for both the `userId` and `language`, this step would be unnecessary.)  Then we partition the resulting promises to separate out the `fulfilled` from the `rejected` ones.  I do this because your question doesn't say what to do with the rejected language lookups.  I choose to add one more entry to the output.  Here as well as `es` and `en`, we also get a list of `userId`s under `_errors`.  If we wanted to ignore these, then we could replace the `partition` with a `filter` and simplify the last step.  That last step takes successful results and the failures, combining the successful ones into an object with our `group` helper, and appending the `_errors`, by mapping the failures to their `userId`s.

It might look like this:

```js
// dummy implementation, resolving to random language, or rejecting with error
const getUserLanguage = (userId) => new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {if (Math.random() < 0.3) resolve("en"); if (Math.random() < 0.6) resolve("es"); reject("Unexpected error.");});
 

// utility functions
const push = (x) => (xs) => 
  (xs .push (x), xs)
const partition = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs .reduce (([y, n], x) => fn (x) ? [push (x) (y), n] : [y, push (x) (n)], [[], []])
const group = (getKey, getValue) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, x, _, __, key = getKey (x)) => ((a [key] = push (getValue (x)) (a[key] ?? [])), a), {})


// main function
const groupUsersByLanguage = (users) => Promise .allSettled (users .map (getUserLanguage))
  .then (ps => ps .map ((p, i) => ({...p, user: users [i]})))
  .then (partition (p => p .status == 'fulfilled'))
  .then (([fulfilled, rejected]) => ({
    ...group (x => x .value, x => x.user) (fulfilled),
    _errors: rejected .map (r => r .user)
  }))


// sample data
const users = ['fred', 'wilma', 'betty', 'barney', 'pebbles', 'bambam', 'yogi', 'booboo']


// demo
groupUsersByLanguage (users)
  .then (console .log)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This yields output like this (YMMV because of the `random` calls):

```js
{
  en: [
    "fred",
    "wilma",
    "barney"
  ],
  es: [
    "bambam",
    "yogi",
    "booboo"
  ],
  _errors: [
    "betty",
    "pebbles"
  ]
}
```

Note that those utility functions are general-purpose.  If we keep our own libraries of such tools handy, we can write functions like this without great effort.

Comment: This could obviously be done with `async/await` instead of `Promise.then`, but I find this reads better and obscures less.

Answer (score 0):

Another option of doing this would be to first fetch all languages using:

```
const languages = await Promise.allSettled(userIds.map(getLanguage));
```

Then zip then together with `userIds` and process them further.

```js
async function getLanguage() {
  if (Math.random() < 0.3) return "en";
  if (Math.random() < 0.6) return "es";
  throw "Unexpected error.";
}

function zip(...arrays) {
  if (!arrays[0]) return;
  return arrays[0].map((_, i) => arrays.map(array => array[i]));
}

async function groupUsersByLanguage(userIds) {
  const languages = await Promise.allSettled(userIds.map(getLanguage));
    
  const groups = {};
  for (const [userId, language] of zip(userIds, languages)) {
    if (language.status != "fulfilled") continue;
    
    groups[language.value] ||= [];
    groups[language.value].push(userId);
  }
  
  return groups;
}

(async () => {
  const userIds = ["Mike", "Walter", "Saul", "Pinkman"];
  const usersGroupedByLanguage = await groupUsersByLanguage(userIds);
  console.log(usersGroupedByLanguage);
})();
```

If you are not interested in creating a `zip()` helper you can use a "normal" for-loop:

```
const groups = {};
for (let i = 0; i < userIds.length; i += 1) {
  if (languages[i].status != "fulfilled") continue;
  
  groups[languages[i].value] ||= [];
  groups[languages[i].value].push(userId);
}
```